# Get newest sql date with where

Tags: sql, datetime, max

This is my query (DateTime is a cloumn with DateTime):

```
SELECT 
    DateTime, Value
FROM
    History
WHERE   
    TagName = 'G_Z'
    AND DateTime > '2017-07-10 07:00:00.000'
    AND DateTime < '2017-07-17 07:00:00.000'
    AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
    AND Value IS NOT NULL
```

I get these results:

```
2017-07-10 08:39:48.1180000 1,89486229419708
2017-07-10 10:19:36.2370000 1,89486229419708
2017-07-10 11:59:24.3560000 1,93500030040741
..and so on...
```

I'm trying to get only the newest value from the query. I tried `SELECT max(DateTime) as Time` but get the error

> Column 'History.Value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So I added at the end `group by Value`. This works but gives me back 10 rows and not only the one with the `max(date)`. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: select top 1???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `max` in the `select`-clause changes the number of returned rows to one (if no `group by` is used), but it does not choose one from DB. The value of `max` is the result of a calculation with the rows in DB as input. This is the reason why your query does not work. An approach to solve the problem is to use a subquery to find out the maximal `DateTime` and select only the row(s) that has this value in the outer query:

```
SELECT DateTime, Value
FROM History
WHERE TagName = 'G_Z'
  AND DateTime > '2017-07-10 07:00:00.000'
  AND DateTime < '2017-07-17 07:00:00.000'
  AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
  and Value is not NULL
  AND DateTime = (
      SELECT max(DateTime)
      FROM History
      WHERE TagName = 'G_Z'
        AND DateTime > '2017-07-10 07:00:00.000'
        AND DateTime < '2017-07-17 07:00:00.000'
        AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
        and Value is not NULL
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use order by and limit instead of max to get the newest value

```
SELECT DateTime, Value
FROM    History
WHERE   TagName = 'G_Z'
AND DateTime > '2017-07-10 07:00:00.000'
AND DateTime < '2017-07-17 07:00:00.000'
AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
and Value is not NULL
order by DateTime desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: The solution probably does not work on all major DBMS.